# Preimages of a function with proofs

Tags: functions, proof-writing

**(a) f^-1((a,b)) for f:ℝ->ℝ, x->f(x) := (x+1)², where a, b are real numbers with a<0, b>0**

(b) **f^-1((0,2)) for f: ℝ->ℝ, x->f(x): = 0 for x<1 and x for x>=1**

Where (a,b) denotes the interval between a and b.

I know how to find a preimage however the fact that it is the preimage of an interval is stumping me, I also have to prove this and am unsure how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

> For $(a)$.

we have $f(\mathbb R)=[0,+\infty)$

thus

$b<0\implies f^{-1}((a,b))=\emptyset$

$b\geq 0\implies f^{-1}((a,b))=f^{-1}([0,b))=(-1-\sqrt{b},-1+\sqrt{b})$

> For $(b)$

$f^{-1}((0,2))=[1,2)$

since if $x<1$ then $f(x)=0$ and if $x\geq2$ then $f(x)=x\geq2$.